# How can I inject all instances as collection IEnumerable<T> that implement a common interface in Prism?

Tags: prism, unity-container

I want to inject all instances as `IEnumerable<T>` that implement a common interface. It is for using it in a strategy pattern resolver. How can I do it? I googled that unity container has a way.

I need this to do the same job as link below.

https://ufukhaciogullari.com/blog/strategy-pattern-with-dependency-injection/

```
    public interface ITest
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestA : ITest
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "A";
    }

    public class TestB : ITest
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "B";
    }

    public class TestC : ITest
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "C";
    }

    public class SomeResolver
    {
        IEnumerable<ITest> _tests;

        public SomeResolver(IEnumerable<ITest> tests)
        {
            _tests = tests;
        }
    }
```

In unity, I can register the following way:

```
container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<IParserBuilder>, IParserBuilder[]>();
```

I tried to do the same in Prism, but it fails. How to do it in Prism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to do the same in Prism, but it fails. How to do it in Prism?

Prism's no dependency injection container, it just tries to hide `IUnityContainer` from you.

That being said, there's no need to register the `IEnumerable<IParserBuilder>` in the first place.

```
container.Resolve<SomeResolver>()
```

will call the constructor and pass it instances of `TestA`, `TestB` and `TestC`, given you registered them first.

```
container.Register<ITest, TestA>( "A" );
container.Register<ITest, TestB>( "B" );
container.Register<ITest, TestC>( "C" );
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to have those `A`, `B` and `C` injected, too, so you have to keep the `Name` property if you need to identify a specific service (I'd make it read-only, though). I'd love to be able to inject `IEnumerable<(string, ITest)>` and get the names, too...